# OnWindowFocusChanged not called when pressing back key from another task

Tags: android

Here is the sequences that triggers my "bug".

I launch my app. Then I receive a new snapchat/sms/anything new. I pull the notification bar from top of my phone and clic on that new snapchat which makes my phone launch the snapchat activity. If now I press the back key it goes back to my app BUT, OnWindowFocusChanged is not changed ! Why ? How do I handle this ?